# What is wrong with SQL syntax 'ALTER TABLE tablename'?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, alter

I'm trying to alter a table to add a new column.

```
ALTER TABLE RKxADR
ADD RK1 varchar(255);
```

I'm getting 'Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE RKxADR' at line 1'.

I've checked several times and the table name is correct. As far as I can tell ALTER TABLE is also the correct syntax.

Any pointers on what may be causing this error?

UPDATE

I tried the below code, got the same error...

```
ALTER TABLE RKxADR
ADD COLUMN RK1 varchar(255);
```

UPDATE II

I tried the below code, got the same error...

```
ALTER TABLE RKxADR;
ADD COLUMN RK1 varchar(255);
```

Comment: What are you trying to add? You say a new row? But it looks like you are trying to add a column named `RK1`, is this correct? Try putting the word `COLUMN` after `ADD`. It might be a version issue from what the error message says.

Comment: typo, I'm trying to add a new column

Comment: I'm trying to add a new column RK1, adding COLUMN didn't seem to work (see update)

Comment: Your second query looks ok: https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=9d7dcecaf388ffa2c45c74978a5cd682&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57 may be error anywhere bwfore

Comment: seems likely there's an error on whatever comes before this ALTER TABLE.  perhaps a missing semi-colon

Comment: nothing comes before ALTER TABLE, it is on line 1. I just tried 'ALTER TABLE RKxADR;' but got the same error.

Comment: MySQL reports syntax errors starting with the word it got confused on. Your syntax looks right, unless there's a non-printing character in there, or one of the characters or the space isn't an ASCII character. There are unicode versions of many characters, and they aren't the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE RKxADR ADD COLUMN RK1 varchar(255) not null DEFAULT(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have tried everything.If its not in production,then you can try command

systemctl restart mysql